# jQuery Custom add attribute

Tags: php, jquery

What I am trying to do is that if the value of the key matches the php code I want it to add a selected attribute in the option. is it possible to collaborate php and jquery?

```
    $('#vessel_sub_category_id').append("<option value=" + key + " "if(key == <?php echo $select_update['vessel_sub_category_id']; ?>){'selected';}" >" + value + "</option>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. But you need to put quotes around string you echo in PHP :)

```
$('#vessel_sub_category_id').append('<option value="' + key + '"' + if(key == '<?php echo $select_update['vessel_category_id']; ?>'){' selected';}+' >' + value + '</option>');
```

There would even be a smarter way to achieve this:

- Make sure [PHP short tags are enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)
- Use [ternary operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

It would look then like this:

```
$('#vessel_sub_category_id').append('<option value="' + key + '"'+ (key == '<?=$select_update['vessel_category_id'];?>'?' selected':'')+' >' + value + '</option>');
```

**Update:** forgot the `+` before the if and afterwards

Comment: sir marc still not displaying the selected value.

Comment: Update: There was a problem with your quoting: Replaced the double quotes with single to make sure the value has double quotes